# Postgres regexp_replace return on pattern match failure

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I'm attempting to write a sql script in postgres. I have two columns: Column A and Column B. Both columns are strings. Column B represents a prefix which was appended to Column A (if B wasn't null). Example: If Column B had "PA" and the value to be added to Column A was "102", then Column A will now contain "PA102." I want to update a new Column C with the value of Column A without the prefix.

I was attempting to use the following:

`regexp_replace(COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, '')`

The documentation for regexp_replace (below) says:

"If the pattern does not match, the function returns no rows."

I need for the method to return the whole string from Column A if Column B doesn't match. Is there some other method (or maybe a flag for regexp_replace) which would accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

regexp_replace docs:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update  mytable set column_c = (select regexp_replace(column_a, column_b, '')  from mytable);
```

works for me, with the key being that you do the regexp_replace as a sub query, and use this for the update.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work. It will return null on no match, then you could wrap it in a coalesce() to fill it in with the original column.

```
select (select regexp_replace(COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, ''))
```

From: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1421790037168-5834795.post@n5.nabble.com